# How to check if a string contain number character after $ sign excluding space in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this to check If a `$` sign exist and replace it.

```
string = '\$'
df= df[df['text'].str.contains(string,case=False)]    
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(string, " dollar ",regex=True)
```

But I want to replace only If the next character is number (excluding spaces)

Sample `df`

```
id   text
1    buy for $1230
2    buy for $1,230
3    buy for $ 1230
4    buy for $ 1,230
5    buy for $abc
```

Expected output:

```
id   text
1    buy for dollar 1230
2    buy for dollar 1,230
3    buy for dollar 1230
4    buy for dollar 1,230
5    buy for $abc
```

Edit: It will be good, If I also get to know the solution to check `If the next character is number (including space)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [positive lookaheads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) so that `$` is replaced only if followed by a number even being preceded by one or more white spaces:

```
df['text'] = (df['text'].str.replace(r'(\$)(?=\d|(?:\s+(?=\d)))', 
             " dollar ", regex=True))

   id   text
0   1   buy for dollar 1230
1   2   buy for dollar 1,230
2   3   buy for dollar  1230
3   4   buy for dollar  1,230
4   5   buy for $abc
```